Why there's no yearly Biblical commemoration for Matan Torah?
In the Torah, Exodus is a serious event that must be remembered and celebrated the same week every year. Multiple Biblical Mitzvos aim at remembering and enacting the event, such as retelling the story to future generations, preparing and eating the sacrifice, consuming Matza, and more. Even Succos is mentioned as the remembrance and enacting of living in Succos in the wilderness (albeit we see no textual mention of the Israelites dwelling in Succos during Exodus).
Matan Torah was, undoubtedly, a pivotal event in the history of Jewish people, however, there's no Mitzvah of remembering that day or event and replicating it yearly. IIRC, the night Torah study (Tikun Leyl Shavuos) was established only in the 16th century.
Why?
Edit: this question is specifically about the Torah view, not Rabbinic commentary.

Ramban holds there is a mitzvah to remember it every day (one of the שש זכירות)

https://www.sefaria.org/Hasagot_HaRamban_on_Sefer_HaMitzvot,_Negative_Commandments_Omitted_by_Rambam_2.1

@DoubleAA The question deals with the Biblical view - the Torah sees no "need" to remember that day - why?

The Ramban is of course being Biblical...רק השמר לך ושמר נפשך מאד פן־תשכח את־הדברים אשר־ראו עיניך ופן־יסורו מלבבך כל ימי חייך והודעתם לבניך ולבני בניך יום אשר עמדת לפני יהוה אלהיך בחרב באמר יהוה אלי הקהל־לי את־העם ואשמעם את־דברי אשר ילמדון ליראה אתי כל־הימים אשר הם חיים על־האדמה ואת־בניהם ילמדון

Maybe for the same reason that some people don't read the 10 dibrot daily (See Babylonian Talmud, Berachot 12a, and Jerusalem Talmud, Berachot 1:5).

@RabbiKaii Right, so the next question would be, why all others, including the Talmud or Rambam, don't think so?

@AlBerko , it is not an iron clad fact that the Rambam disagrees, rav moshe Shapiro zatzal explained that according to the Rambam the mitzvah of talmud torah is to perpetuate mamaad Har Sinai. It's printed in the shuirim from him on hilchos talmud torah, and if you want, this is also available on recording.

@אילפא I didn't mean disagrees like "objects to" but doesn't see/count it as a biblical obligation.

@RabbiKaii You (and others here) are right about Ramban, but when comparing it to Pesach or Succos, I wondered why there's no yearly commemoration. So I edited the title to fit the question.

@AlBerko Shavuot?

In addition, we have no idea where Sinai is located. If the giving of the Torah is a great event, why don't we know where sinai is?

What does "Torah View, not Rabbinic commentary" mean - מדארייתא vs. מדרבנן?

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/104556/759

The Kli Yakar in parshas Emor addresses why there is no mention in the Torah that Shevous is commemorating Matan Torah. He says since the Torah is a constant, and is always supposed to be viewed anew, Hashem didn't make any particular day the explicit commemoration, as that would limit it to one day. Rather every day should be view as a new day of receiving the Torah.

Right, posterior apologetics. Why can't every day be seen as Pesach or Yom Kippur?

This specific question has actually bothered R. Nathan Laufer to write an entire book about it. "Rendezvous with God. Revealing the Meaning of the Jewish Holidays and Their Mysterious Rituals". He said in the podcast on Judaism Demystified that it is inconceivable that the celebration of the experience of receiving of the Torah has not found its way into Judaic holiday experience. Specifically, he makes the point that the holiday of Rosh haShanah, which we call Yom haZikaron, is about rememberance. Rememberance of what? Which day do we need to remember when facing Hashem's Judgement? He points out, based on what we do on Rosh haShanah is that we are remembering the day when we stood at har Sinai when receiving the Torah. Facing the Judgement of G-d is the awesome experience, which can certainly compare with what happened at Mt. Sinai, when people were dying and getting revived. (Recall Unesaneh Tokef).
During musaf of Rosh Hashanah we recite 10 verses for each of the malkiyoth, zichronoth, and shofaroth blessings. This corresponds to 10 dibroth. Many congregations opt to blow shofar 10 times right after each one of the blessings, both in the silent tefilah and in the repetition. One blow for each saying. That's also exactly a reference to the Sinai experience.
I think R. Laufer's point that Matan Torah and standing at Har Sinai is hinted on Rosh Hashanah, the celebrated Day of Creation, can be found in the second Rashi comment on the Torah in parashat Bereshis: Bereshis Bara (In the beginning of G-d's Creating): This verse says nothing but "Explain me!" It is to be understood as as the Rabbis of the blessed memory expounded it: For the Torah, which is called "The beginning of His way", and for Israel, who are called "the first of His crop". Here's where Rosh Hashanah (act of creation) got connected to Matan Torah with gzeira shava.

Thank you, an interesting insight.

Thank you for this answer and book recommendation

The Torah isn't shy about telling the future. The Torah recounts how God promised Abraham he will be a great people in the future, he will inherit the land of Israel and that his descendants will sojourn for hundreds of years and be enslaved. But where's the prophecy of the giving of the Torah? I haven't found such a prophecy, have you?
The closest hint I've seen is that when God is about to destroy Sodom and Amorah God mentions that Abraham will teach his descendants righteousness and justice... But we also don't see that happen. Can anyone point to a story in which Isaac's Torah knowledge and righteousness is on display? Jacob and Esau don't seem like they're being raised in righteousness and justice, but rather strife and jealousy. Which makes their redemption into righteous loving brothers so much more powerful in my opinion, but regardless. Why isn't the Torah talking about the wonderful Torah these people should have been learning/living?
My answer is that God might not have perceived as handing the Torah over as one of His original plans. Afterall, God seems to believe that we humans can intuit some things as right vs wrong naturally, otherwise how could God be angry at Adam for disobeying? Or warning Kain to try and dissuade him from letting his anger/jealousy consume him into murdering his brother. I don't believe God always planned to give Kain a mark, but instead chose to be in relation with Kain and humans and therefore gave Kain a mark. I believe the same is true with the Torah.
God wants to be in relation with us. And so I don't think it's fruitful to talk about whether God is perfect or not, whether God changes Their mind or not. Because regardless of God's attributes/actions, the relationship will only survive if God is in relation to our attributes/actions. Our relationship with God is described as parent child and husband wife, both of these relationships require both parties to change and adapt to each other.
And therefore it seems to me that God saw the golden calf, saw Moses as a worthy figure of teaching the people, and then for the good of us, His now chosen people, He gave us the Torah through Moses who merited being the one to teach it. God didn't change His mind, God was in relation to Moses and the Israelites. But it seems to me that God didn't give the Torah to the whole nation, He gave it to Moses, which would explain why we lack a national celebration.

While we do find https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.38a.4 the gemara itself limits it to pilpul. The question is within the framework that it was Hashems will to give the torah to klal yisroel, and it was a meaningful national event.

I appreciate you providing a link instead of just silently downvoting me. Would love to know why I'm getting so many downvotes

+1 Thank you for the insight. This community doesn't handle heterodoxy well. I agree that the Torah doesn't see itself as Rabbis do.

You believe G-d changes His mind?

God may not have intended to give the Torah over well then that all was just a big ol' whoops-a-daisy, wasn't it

To support your view, according to the Lurianic Kabbala, Matan Torah was a posterior measure to compensate for the early leave from Egypt. Theoretically, the Torah would remain "Oral" and never be encapsulated in finite words. This is why the Hassidim look at the white Gvil when saying "This is the Torah that Moses gave".

@robev read my comment. Is this the first time God changed his mind? Isn't the Torah full of God's whims?

@Yehuda Please read my comment above.

@Yehuda I didn't intend to teach my daughter about multiplication at 5 or how many zeros are in a trillion. But she merited it and so I changed my plans

@robev I'm not convinced that God changes His mind. However, God is in relation to us, finite beings who change their minds. So I believe for God to be in a real relationship with us, He has to respond to the situations we cause in the world. The Torah reads to me that God was contemplating giving the Torah to Abraham, but I don't think Abraham was found worthy. And so God put the issue to the side until Moses was found worthy.

@AlBerko I've made some edits to my answer, hopefully they are helpful

Did you know, that the attribution of Biblical commandments straight to God is unique in the Torah as the opposite of codexes of other nations who had half-divine kings? Many try to present Moses as a king, but it is not in the scripture. So your hypothesis seems incorrect.

@AlBerko The Torah doesn't present Moses as king. Nor that he invented the laws. Moses was willing to be written out of Gods Torah and that's why he was deemed worthy to hand it over to Israel.

I said "many [commentators] try but it is not in the scripture". Undoubtedly, Moses was a worthy character, but IIRC, Judaism holds that Moses relayed the Torah exactly as God dictated.

@AlBerko I don't see how what I've said goes against that. There's no conflict of saying "God didn't plan to give the Torah until Moses showed himself worthy," and "Moses relayed the Torah exactly as given to him."

Worthy of what? In the end, the Torah was meant for Israel, not Moses. If the transmission was exact, he was merely a tool, not a source, right?

I never claimed Moses was a source. But my argument is if not for Moses being who he was, we might not have received the Torah "until Ezra." The narrative doesn't give any hint that the Israelites were worthy to receive the Torah.
